Which of the following relationships between a P-matrix and a positive definite matrix are true?
This question has just been asked before What is the relationship between a P-matrix and a positive definite matrix?
but I am not sure it was answered. My impression is the term P-matrix is used in applied dynamical systems, for example, where matrices are always real and usually non-symmetric.  Some  possible relationships therefore could be:

A real  positive definite matrix is $P$.
A symmetric  $P$ matrix is positive definite
If a  matrix is $P$, then $(P + P^t)$ is positive definite
A   $P$ matrix  satisfies $x P x^t >0$ for any nonzero vector $x$

Which of these 4 statements is False?

$xPx^t$ doesn’t make sense if $x$ is supposed to be a vector. Did you mean $x^tPx > 0$? In that case this is just equivalent to positive definite.

But P is not necessarily symmetric

@goldboy Ah, yes, sorry, I was thinking about the complex case. For the real case $x^tPx > 0$ for all $x$ is equivalent to $P + P^t$ being positive definite.

Yes, but it’s not one of those 4 statements

I suppose that $x$ is a real row vector in 4. Then statements 3 and 4 are equivalent and they are false. Consider $P=\pmatrix{3&8\ 1&3}$ for instance.


Statement 1 (True): If A is positive definite (PD), meaning all leading principal minors are positive (and also all principal minors are positive in this case$^*$), hence A is P matrix

Statement 2 (True): P matrix have all principal minors being positive which includes all leading principal minors, hence symmetric P matrix is PD.

Statements 3 & 4 (False), as @user1551 showed a simple counterexample.


*[Corollary 7.1.5] R.A. Horn, C.R. Johnson, Matrix Analysis, second ed., Cambridge University Press, New York, 2013.
